# What are the pre steps of Object Recognition (before performing SIFT/SURF )

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am an IT engineer student. 
My intention is to work on Landmark Guide System which is related to AR.
Part of that project is of course object recognition.
Currently my task is to recognize object from (webcam)
That's why I tried to use image histogram on openCV to select relative images to frame from dataset.So then i can perform SURF in a few images.
But the result is terrible. Almost all images gave the same result after comparing histograms.

I have
10200 ukbenchmark image datasets

from given frame i should recognize the object among 10200 images. But to perform SURF with that amount is impossible. I need to select somehow relative(potential for matching) images. 
How to select images so i don't have to perform SURF with every single image?
Is there any way to exploit image histograms to solve this problem? 
I would greatly appreciate your help guys!

Here is my dataset
[image: ukbenchmark dataset]

Here is histogram comparision results[image: histogram comparision]

Here is my code based on opencv

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat src;

  /// Establish the number of bins
  int histSize = 256;

  /// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
  float range[] = { 0, 256 } ;
  const float* histRange = { range };

  bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;

  Mat gray_hist;
    // Draw the histograms for B, G and R
  int hist_w = 512; int hist_h = 400;
  int bin_w = cvRound( (double) hist_w/histSize );

  char * filename=new char[100];

  //cycle starts here
  int begin=getTickCount();
  Mat inputImage=imread("frame3.jpg",1);//this is given input image
  cvtColor(inputImage,inputImage,COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Mat inputImageHist;
    equalizeHist(inputImage,inputImage);
     calcHist( &inputImage, 1, 0, Mat(), inputImageHist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
        normalize( inputImageHist, inputImageHist, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    /// Load image
    sprintf(filename,"D:\\labworks\\ukbenchmark\\full\\ukbench%05d.jpg",i);
    src = imread( filename, 1 );
    Mat srcGray;
    cvtColor(src,srcGray,COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    //this commented lines are to show what i store in files
    ///// Apply Histogram Equalization
    //equalizeHist( srcGray, srcGray);
    //calcHist( &srcGray, 1, 0, Mat(), gray_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
    //normalize( gray_hist, gray_hist, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    /// Compute the histograms:
    sprintf(filename,"histogramEqualized\\ukbench%05d.yml",i);
    FileStorage fs(filename,FileStorage::READ);
    fs["myHistogram"]>>gray_hist;
    fs.release();

    int histDif=compareHist(gray_hist,inputImageHist,1);
    cout<<filename<<"\t:\t"<<histDif<<endl;

  }
  //cycle ends here

    system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Now I have 3 days left till i show demo to my professor. so I assume I have no time to read paper* - too bad. Plan better next semester.

Comment: yeah, probably you right! Ok, I am ready to read a paper.

Comment: you only have to compute SIFT/SURF once for each image, just save the keypoints and descriptors to a database or sth. After that you can cluster the images with k-means++ or sth. Then for your live image, choose the best cluster(s) and compare only to images of that cluster.

Comment: ah, just thought about it, since you have multiple keypoints for each image, simple clustering doesnt work, but there are techniques to filter/find the best assumed images from your database. Histograms indeed might be a way: cluster 2D color histograms with k-means ;)